# nodejs worker thread shared memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, shared-memory, worker-thread

I am trying to use worker threads with the worker pool in my application which is intended to be running in a 256mb docker containers.

My main thread is taking around 30mb of memory and 1 worker thread to be taking around 25mb of memory (considering require of third party node modules). Considering this, I would only be able to create a pool of ~7 workers.

But my application requirements are such that it should be able to handle many jobs at a time by creating many workers up and listening for a job (like around 20 or more).

Is there any way wherein I can use the third-party modules like (lodash, request, etc) to be shared across worker threads to save memory it needs in requiring all necessary modules.

My initial thought process was like I can give a try with shared memory (SharedArrayBuffer) but then it will not work as it won't allow passing such complex object structure and functions.

Can anyone help me what can be a possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see any reason to spawn more worker threads than you have available cores in your container. Additionally, there is no point in creating threads to serve I/O, should this be what you want to do. In case you are going to do anything CPU-bound, I would create n-1 worker threads and submit jobs to them from the main thread.